# Angular animation on scroll

Tags: css, angular, animation, css-animations

I build an webpage with angular, each module is an component it has an animation in it but it runs only when the page opens but I need to perform the animation while the component is visibile on the screen. I just tried below like hide and show the component by checking the scrollY of the page. Is there any better way to do it?

```
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onWindowScroll(e: any) {
    if (window.pageYOffset < 180) {
      this.heroShown = 0;
    } else {
      this.heroShown = 1;
    }
    console.log(e.target['scrollingElement'].scrollTop);
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

for that you can use a [Intersection Observer](https://giancarlobuomprisco.com/angular/intersection-observer-with-angular).
The observer fires an event when the element is visible.
So when the event fires you can start your animation.

```
private createObserver() {
    const options = {
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: this.threshold,
    };

    const isIntersecting = (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry) =>
      entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0;

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (isIntersecting(entry)) {
          this.subject$.next({ entry, observer });
        }
      });
    }, options);
  }
```

a other way to archive this is using a framwork like [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap/)
There you can use something like a scrolltrigger.
Check the docs [here](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/).